# How to make database table, Python Django

Tags: python, django

I learn Django. And now I try to make new database table.
I have done the structure of the files, as in the book, which I learn. My app is named - "books":

[image: Structure of the files]

Then, I must add the line ‘mysite.books’ to field INSTALLED_APPS, in settings.py, isn`t it?
Also, in the book, written, that I must comment out next lines in the file "settings.py":

```
 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
 # ‘django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware’,
 # ‘django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware’,
 # ‘django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware’,
)
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 # ‘django.contrib.auth’,
 # ‘django.contrib.contenttypes’,
 # ‘django.contrib.sessions’,
 # ‘django.contrib.sites’,
 ‘mysite.books’,
)
```

But, the book about Django, is for 1.1 version of Django, and I use the 1.8 version of Django. So, I have some another fields "MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES" and "INSTALLED_APPS":

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    #'django.contrib.auth',
    #'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.messages',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.books',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

And, if I run the command "python manage.py validate", i see the error: "ImportError: No module named 'mysite.books'"

What I do wrong? Or, maybe it is the problem with different versions of Django? What I must doing?

Comment: What happens if you put the app in installed apps as 'books'?

Comment: You might find it easier if you use a more recent book. Django 1.1 was released in 2009, a lot has changed since then.

Comment: Note that Django 1.1 is almost six years old -- really really ancient. You're probably better off doing the official Django tutorial for 1.8.

Comment: I understand, that Django 1.1 is very old, by I have not any another book about Django at this momment.

Comment: also keep note that you need not have to comment the other INSTALLED_APPS. Putting 'books' instead of 'mysite.books' should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put `books` without the prefix `mysite`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Validate work super. result:'System check identified no issues (0 silenced).'.. But next I must run command "python manage.py sqlall books". And it cause: "CommandError: App 'books' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations." What is it?

Comment: I think your doc reference is outdated. Please refer to the [Django1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/topics/migrations/)

Comment: Ok, I will try to read the official documentation. But, what I do wrong?

Comment: @Q-bart: migrations are a new feature introduced in Django 1.7. You should disable migrations for your model if you want to use `sqlall` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

The default Django project layout [changed in Django 1.4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py).

For the directory layout you have shown you should use `books` instead of `mysite.books` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.